# I need a token to be passed to different functions in JS but it is always undefined. tried Callback but not sure how to implement

Tags: javascript, callback

**Here is getToken function that will be called by many functions in order to execute:**

```
export function getToken() {

     axios.post(tokenUrl, requestData, requestConfig)
         .then((response) => {
             console.log(" TOKEN: "+ response.statusText, response.data)
             token = response.data.token
             return token
         })
         .catch((error) => {
             console.log("TOKEN ERROR: ", error);
         })
}
```

**And the token is used by other function (and other similar functions):**

```
export async function useToken() {

const token = await getToken()
console.log(`${token}`);

let requestConfig = {
    headers: {
       'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
};
axios.post(totpUrl, requestData, requestConfig)
   .then((response) => {
        console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", response)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR: ", error);
    })
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function getToken doesn't return token. It returns undefined. Just add 'return' before axios.

Answer (score 0):

If I read it right, you are trying to call a sync function out of an async function, that's a not so straight forward thing as one would expect.

Try to use a promise in the sync function. Something like this (not tested) should enable you to use "await" as you tried:

```
function getToken() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(tokenUrl, requestData, requestConfig)
         .then((response) => {
             console.log(" TOKEN: "+ response.statusText, response.data)
             token = response.data.token
             resolve(token)
         })
         .catch((error) => reject(error) )      
    });
}
```